# How to see untrimmed logs on Heroku Local

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I'm running a NodeJS app on heroku local, however all my console.log statements and error messages get trimmed.

For example:

```
forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
web.1  | module.js:339
```

I don't see the full error logs. How to avoid this trimming of error messages?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: BTW, you can start the app without heroku using something like `node bin/www` and see the output there.

Comment: @UrK But what about environment variables that heroku local provides?

Comment: They have to be simulated in this case regretfully. This is why this was not submitted as an answer but as a comment.

Answer (score 13):

`heroku local` will run whatever processes you tell it to in the Procfile. If you'd like to stream your development log, simply add something like `log: tail -f log/development.log` to your Procfile. You'll also want to make sure that you create a second Procfile (I use `Procfile.dev`) for this. Replace the log file path with wherever your desired log file is located.

Cheers!

Answer (score -6):

Did you try?

```
$ heroku help local
```

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local

Is this deployed already? If so:

On terminal/bash:

```
$ heroku logs
```

On your heroku account:

1) Go to you account and then apps and then the log for that app