# How to view heroku logs when running an app locally?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I'm running my heroku app locally using `heroku local web` with this being the only line in my Procfile:

`web:node index.js`

---

How can I get it to print live logs while running locally?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156205/how-to-see-untrimmed-logs-on-heroku-local), but there are some things missing from that explanation, and I'm struggling with it, since I'm new to heroku.  Any help is appreciated.